# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable with my code?

Tags: python

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))

bitcion.loc['2019','Close'].plot()

bitcion.loc['2019'],['Close'].resample('M').std().plot(label='moyenne par mois',lw=3,ls=':', alpha=0.8)

bitcion.loc['2019'],['Close'].resample('W').std().plot(label='moyenne par semaine',lw=2,ls='--', 

alpha=0.8)

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

**output**

[image]

Comment: Please add more context to your question. What module are you trying to use? Where are your inputs? Python 2 or 3? It looks like 3, but which version?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is what causes the error because you don't show how you imported your modules: 
make sure you import the pyplot function like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```